# Importar una función que está dentro de otra

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, unittest

Estoy haciendo test a funciones con `unittest`, pero tengo un problema a la hora de hacer pruebas a una función que está dentro de otra.

Un Ejemplo muy básico de lo que pretendo sería lo siguiente.
Teniendo una estructura de archivos así:

```
Folder
|---main.py
|---test.py
```

En `main.py` una función en la que dentro está definida otra función:

```
def funcion(p):
    def subfuncion(x,y):
        return x+y
    return p**subfuncion(4,5)

print(funcion(2))
```

En `test.py` esto:

```
import unittest
from main import funcion

class TestScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_subfuncion(self):
        a,b = 2,2
        expected = 4
        self.assertEqual(subfuncion(a,b), expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Entiendo que `subfuncion(x,y)` no se define hasta que no se llama a `funcion(p)`, por lo que la línea `self.assertEqual(subfuncion(a,b), expected)` me dice (como es lógico) que `subfuncion` no está definida.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder hacer los test a esa `subfunción`? Se me ocurre sacarla fuera de `función` hasta que haga lo que necesito y luego volverla a meter, pero no sé si hay alguna forma más correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La subfunción solo existe mientras la `funcion()` se esté ejecutando. No es sólo que `funcion()` no se haya ejecutado aún, sino que aún si ejecutas `funcion()`, `subfuncion()` seguiría sin ser testeable, pues tan pronto como `funcion()` retorne, `subfuncion()` dejará de existir.

Cuando quieres que una subfunción siga existiendo fuera, debe retornarse la subfunción. Pero entiendo que no es ese el objetivo en tu caso. No defines `subfuncion()` dentro de `funcion()` porque `subfuncion()` deba acceder a variables o parámetros de `funcion()`, sino simplemente como una cuestión organizativa, porque de algún modo el trabajo que hace `subfuncion()` sólo es útil para `funcion()`.

Aún así, no es aconsejable definir la  `subfuncion()` como interna. Hacerlo así te impide testearla como estás descubriendo.

Quizás la mejor solución sea hacer `subfuncion()` externa, pero ponerle un `_` delante del nombre. Este es un **convenio** en Python que significa que esa función no es para ser utilizada desde fuera. Es una funcion "interna" (o "privada" dirían otros) que sólo debe ser usada por otras funciones de ese módulo.

Esto no deja de ser un convenio. Python no impide de ningún modo que invoques `_subfuncion()` desde fuera, por lo que podrías hacerlo desde un test. Pero para cualquier pythonista el `_` en el nombre es un indicador de que "lo que haga esa función no me importa, ni debo usarla desde mi programa".

Con este enfoque tu código sería así:

```
def _subfuncion(x,y):
    return x+y

def funcion(p):
    return p**_subfuncion(4,5)

print(funcion(2))
```

Y tu test así:

```
import unittest
import main

class TestScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_subfuncion(self):
        a,b = 2,2
        expected = 4
        self.assertEqual(main._subfuncion(a,b), expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Si la subfuncion necesitara acceder a variables locales o parámetros de `funcion()`, entonces ya no podrías hacerlo así. Pero es que en ese caso tampoco podrías testearla separadamente, ya que necesariamente debe ser ejecutada desde `funcion()` para poder acceder a toda la información necesaria. En ese caso los test unitarios irían sobre `funcion()`.

### Bonus

Por si pudiera interesarte (aunque es una práctica que no recomiendo), también podrías resolver tu problema haciendo uso de **atributos de función**.

Esto es una característica poco usada de python, pero ya que **las funciones son también objetos**, pueden tener atributos. Es decir, es legal hacer `funcion.algo = loquesea`, y entonces puedes acceder a `funcion.algo` una vez que esa asignación haya sido ejecutada.

Usando atributos, puedes crear un atributo dentro de `funcion` llamado por ejemplo `subfuncion` que apunte a la función interna:

```
def funcion(p):
    def subfuncion(x,y):
        return x+y
    funcion.subfuncion = subfuncion
    return p**subfuncion(4,5)
```

Si ahora ejecutas por ejemplo `funcion(1)` obtienes la respuesta `1`, y de paso queda definido el símbolo `funcion.subfuncion` apuntando a la función interna. Por tanto ese simbolo ya es usable desde fuera: `funcion.subfuncion(4,5)` produce `9`. Así que ya es testeable.

Fijate que hay que ejecutar `funcion()` antes al menos una vez para que `funcion.subfuncion` quede definido. Puedes hacer eso tras definir la funcion para asegurarte de que así sea:

```
def funcion(p):
    def subfuncion(x,y):
        return x+y
    funcion.subfuncion = subfuncion
    return p**subfuncion(4,5)

funcion(0)
```

Así al hacer `import main` tendrás `main.funcion` y `main.funcion.subfuncion`.

No obstante todo este lío no aporta realmente ninguna ventaja sobre la solución inicialmente propuesta de usar un nombre global con `_` delante.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la explicación. Efectivamente con la solución de sacarla fuera y hacerla interna me vale. Por añadir algo más a tu explicación, por si a alguien le sirve, había encontrado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504741/importing-a-function-inside-another-function/52504826) buscando más información. Muchas gracias!